# expanding Centos_home

Tags: linux, centos

i have centOS running on hyper -v , i expanded the virtual hard disk in hyper-v but i need to expand  centos_home partition.

i need a way to increase the size of the sda3 since all the free space allocated on sda root without losing my  data .

this is the lsblk and df - lcommand :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use LVM it's not need to change the partitions. Moreover you use virtualization so the steps are:

1. Add new harddisk to the virtual machine
2. Reboot the machine
3. Create PV on the new disk `pvcreate /dev/sdb` (suppose `/dev/sdb` is
   your new disk)
4. Add this new volume to the VG `vgextend centos /dev/sdb`
5. Extend the home LV `lvresize -L<amount of space you want to add>
   /dev/mapper/centos-home`
6. Extend the filesystem `/home` `resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-home`

P.S. If you want to use the space from root LV you should restart with some live CD because shrink process need to have LV to be unmounted